# Clearing the entry box text when clicking a button

Tags: python, mysql-python

I dont know what i got wrong but i used this code to clear the entry box text when the user click on a button. I have done the referencing and everything and the code compiles but pressing the clear button doesnt clear the entry box and i am not getting any errors. Can you help please.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Pmw

#=============================================================================
app = Tk()
app.title("Testing")

#the variable
bv = IntVar()

#the entry box
b1 = Entry(app, textvariable=bv)

b1.pack()

#=============================================================================
def test():
    print bv.get() 
#=============================================================================
bu1 = Button(app, text="PRESS", command=test)


#packing button 1
bu1.pack()

#button 2 referencing b1
bu2 = Button(app, text="CLEAR", command=b1.delete(0,END))

#packing button 2
bu2.pack()

#the mainloop
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting your command out into a function:

```
def clear_textbox():
    b1.delete(0, END)

bu2 = Button(app, text='CLEAR', command=clear_textbox)
```

Comment: Works like a breeze man, Thank you so much, Took me 2 days in vain!